# Subclassing NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, core-data

I made a subclass of NSManagedObject for my Story model.  I create several new stories like so:

```
Story *newStory = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Story" inManagedObjectContext:context];

...

[stories addObject:newStory];
```

And then later on:

```
Story *story = [stories objectAtIndex:[indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length] - 1]];
```

However, it turns out that `[story class]` is actually NSManagedObject, not Story, for some reason, and when I try to call a method that I defined on Story, it says `unrecognized selector`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you specify the class that you want to use for your `NSManagedObject`. You do this in Xcode's data model editor. The "Class" field is right below the "Name" field in the Entity inspector.

Comment: In Xcode 4.3 (and perhaps previous versions?), you need to go to your .xcdatamodeld file, then under the "CONFIGURATIONS" option you should have one or more configurations (I just have one called "Default"). In there, you need to match up your Entity with a Class to get it to work properly. Just double click in the white space and type in your class name (e.g. Person).